# How to display data from dataset in a html table from .cs

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp table and working dataset.How can I bind the dataset with the table.The code is here....

```
<asp:table id="tblcampaign" runat="server" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="content_table_heading">
    <asp:TableHeaderCell Width="39"><img src="Images/table_heading_bg_lft.gif" alt="" width="39" height="41" /></asp:TableHeaderCell>
    <asp:TableCell width="91">Campaign ID</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell width="132">Campaign Name</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell width="134">Parent Campaign</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell width="121">Target Segment</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell width="95">Objective</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell width="130">Planned Start Date</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell width="134">Planned End Date</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell width="52">Status</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell width="39"><img src="Images/table_heading_bg_rt.gif" alt="" width="39" height="41" /></asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableHeaderRow>
     <asp:TableRow>
     <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="10"><img src="Images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="8" /></asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableRow CssClass="tr_style1">
   <asp:TableCell>&nbsp;</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell CssClass="table_text_style2">01</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell ><a href="#">abc entertainment</a></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell >None</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell >Segment 1</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell >Objective 1</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell CssClass="table_text_style2">01/01/2010</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell CssClass="table_text_style2">01/01/2010</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell >Planned</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>&nbsp;</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
```

.cs code is here..

```
MCMS.DAL.Dataset.MobileCampaign mob_cam = new MCMS.DAL.Dataset.MobileCampaign();
MCMS.BL.MobileCampaignHandler obj = new MCMS.BL.MobileCampaignHandler();
mob_cam = obj.GetCampaignDetails();
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you're not using a Gridview for this?

What you need to do is for every row in your DataSet, create a new TableRow, create the cells, and add it to the table, something like:

```
//Build a row for each record in the DataSet
foreach (DataRow myDataRow in MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    TableRow myTableRow = new TableRow();

    //Add a cell for each column in the DataSet
    for (int i = 0; i < myDataRow.ItemArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        TableCell myTableCell = new TableCell();
        myTableCell.Text = myDataRow[i].ToString();
        myTableRow.Cells.Add(myTableCell);
    }

    //Add the row to the table
    tblcampaign.Rows.Add(myTableRow);
}
```

But a Gridview's much easier...